# Trouble using SVG retrieved from database (UTF-8 error)

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, svg, batik

I'm getting an error "Invalid byte 2 of 3 byte UTF-8 sequence" when I try to use SVG code retrieved from a SQL table in a Batik transcoding.

A svg drawing pulled from the DOM by jQuery and is sent to a cfc via jQuery Ajax where it is updated into a SQL table. On another separate page the SVG code is queried from the table and I attempt to use Batik to transcode it into a PNG file. At that point I'm getting the Invalid UTF-8 Sequence error.

Code to save the data:

```
var lclSVG = $('#holderDiv')[0].innerHTML;
$.ajax({ 
type: "POST",
url: "dbNIS.cfc?method=saveSketch", 
data: ({orderID: ordID, sketch_svg: lclSVG}),
dataType: "json",
success: function(saveData) {alert(saveData.CODE);}
});
```

Code from CFC where SVG code is saved into table:

```
<cffunction name="saveSketch" access="remote" output="no" returntype="struct" returnFormat="JSON">
<cfargument name="orderID" type="string" default="" required="Yes" hint="Order ID">
<cfargument name="sketch_svg"  type="string" default="" required="Yes" hint="Sketch SVG Data">
<CFQUERY NAME="updateSketch">
  UPDATE sketch
  SET sketch_svg = '#arguments.sketch_svg#'
  WHERE  ordID = #arguments.orderID#
</CFQUERY>
</cffunction>
```

Code where SVG is retrieved from table and used in transcoding to PNG:

```
<CFQUERY NAME="getSketch">
  SELECT sketch_svg AS svg
  FROM sketch
  WHERE  ordID = 1
</CFQUERY>
<cfscript>
  transcoder = createObject("java", "org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder").init();
  inputStream = createObject("java", "java.io.StringBufferInputStream").init(getSketch.svg);
  input = createObject("java", "org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput").init(inputStream);
  OutFile = expandPath("myTest.png");
  outputStream=CreateObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init(OutFile);
  output=CreateObject("java", "org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput").init(outputStream);
  transcoder.transcode(input, output);
  outputStream.close();
</cfscript>
```

NOTE: I've instead tried sending the svg to an action page where I update it into a table, immediately retrieve it from that table, and then transcode it which works fine. So it seems to me that I must be doing something wrong with the charset when sending through ajax, or when updating/retrieving from the table. Please help if you can...

I've narrowed it down some more. When I enter the svg directly into the table then the third section works fine... So it must be a problem with the way the data is being sent in the ajax call where the svg is sent to the cfc to be stored in the table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery ajax seems to alter SVG data sent to coldfusion server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216397/jquery-ajax-seems-to-alter-svg-data-sent-to-coldfusion-server)